# making a flat list out of a list of lists where the elements are strings

Tags: python, list

I know a similar question was asked here [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

But when the elements of the lists are strings, this method does not cut it:

```
arr = [['i', 'dont'], 'hi']
[item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]
>>['i', 'dont', 'h', 'i']
```

what I need is:

```
["I", "dont", "hi"]
```

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify `arr` so that all top-level strings become enclosed in a list. Then the usual list flattening methods will work properly.

```
arr = [['i', 'dont'], 'hi']
arr = [[item] if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in arr]
#arr is now [['i', 'dont'], ['hi']]
print [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]
```

Result:

```
['i', 'dont', 'hi']
```

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a way to do it using your method, but I find that not too readable.

```
def outlist(li, flatlist):
    if isinstance(li, str):
        flatlist.append(li)
    elif len(li) > 1:
        for i in li:
            outlist(i, flatlist)

flatlist = []
outlist([['test', 'test2'], 'test3'], flatlist)
print(flatlist)
```

Comment: The recursive call to `outlist()` appears to be a syntax error

Comment: -1: This won't flatten correctly if there are tuples, sets, etc. Rather than singling out `list`, you should single out `string`, since it's probably the only iterable you would want to treat specially.

Comment: oops fixed, changed function to append to a list instead of what it originally did (printing) and also  updated to check isinstance(string) which is a good idea.